# Why is a `return` statement inside of except block silently not executed if finally block contains a return statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

The following code prints `JUST KIDDING` to the console. Why does it not print "`HIGH FIVE ME!`"?

```
def f():
    print("`f` is being called")
    try:
        raise ValueError()
        raise AttributeError()
        raise type("Hell", (Exception,), dict())
    except BaseException as exc:
        print("we are in the except block")
        # WHY IS "HIGH FIVE ME!" NOT RETURNED?
        return "HIGH FIVE ME!"
    finally:
        return "JUST KIDDING"

print(f())
```

If that's the desired behavior, is it possible to implement something like the following pseudo-code?

```
If:
    finally clause, `fin` exists
        and:
    there exists except block `exc` in `fin` such that:
        there exists a return statement in `exc`
then:
    raise terrible horrible bad ugly exception
```

Comment: I don't follow your pseudo-code. Could you write it a bit less pseudo and more code?

Comment: Hey Toothpick Anemone, if you'd be willing to edit your question as to clarify the pseudo-code, I'd be happy to amend my answer. I think I managed to answer the rest of it. or didn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `finally` is executed before exiting the `try` block. In fact, `finally` is always executed (to allow for some "clean-up" even if an error occurred). From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

> If a `finally` clause is present, the `finally` clause will execute as the last task before the try statement completes. The finally clause runs whether or not the `try` statement produces an exception.

In fact, even a `return` in `try` block would not get executed, try:

```py
def f():
    print("`f` is being called")
    try:
        return "HIGH FIVE ME!"
    except BaseException as exc:
        pass
    finally:
        return "JUST KIDDING"
```

Just a few lines after the first quote:

> If a `finally` clause includes a `return` statement, the `finally` clause’s `return` statement will execute before, **and instead of**, the `return` statement in a `try` clause.

(My emphasis.) I guess it's safe to say the same holds for `except`.